# Second Order Linear Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is that find the general solution of differential equation
$y"$-$2y'$+$y$=$e^x$

i know that $y_c$=A$x$$e^x$ + B$e^x$

then let the $f(x)$=$e^x$ , so $y$=$p$$x$$e^x$ as $f(x)$ is in the complementary function.
so  $y'$=$p$$e^x$$(x+1)$
    $y"$=$p$$e^x$$(x+2)$ 
then i put it into equation,but the answer is ($0$)$p$$e^x$=$e^x$,then i can't find the unknown number $p$.

May i ask that which step am i wrong? thank you so much

Comment: $y_T(x)=pxe^x$ is also in the complementary/homogenous solution... try $y_T(x)=px^2e^x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're off to a good start.

The fact that you ended up with the equation $0=e^x$ isn't due to any calculation error on your part, but rather is because $y(x)=Axe^x+Be^x$ is a solution to the homogeneous system, since then $$y'=Axe^x+Ae^x+Be^x=y+Ae^x$$ and $$y''=y'+Ae^x=y+2Ae^x,$$ so that $$y''-2y'+y=y+2Ae^x-2(y+Ae^x)+y=0.$$

Your general idea is a good one, though. Instead, consider $$y(x)=(Ax^2+Bx+C)e^x,$$ and try that in your system, solving for what parameters you can, and leaving the rest as free parameters

Comment: it is very helpful for me, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As a quick method of solving this problem quickly, note that multiplying both sides by $e^{-x}$ yields

$$e^{-x}y''-2e^{-x}y'+e^{-x}y=(e^{-x}y)''=1$$

To see this you could note that

$$y''-2y'+y=(y'-y)'-(y'-y)$$

for which the appropriate integrating factor would be $e^{-x}$.  And after integrating, $y'-y$ has the same integrating factor.  Or it's easy to show that

$$(uv)''=u''v+2u'v'+uv''$$

Once in the appropriate form, all that is needed is to integrate both sides twice to yield

$$e^{-x}y=\frac12x^2+ax+b,y=(\frac12x^2+ax+b)e^x$$

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use differential operators.

$\frac{e^x}{(D-1)^2}$=$\frac{x^2}{2!}e^x$. This is the solution for $y_p$.
The general solution is obtained with $y_c$+$y_p$.